# Fuzzy live search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to implement a fuzzy live(autocomplete) search in Rails. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Use Sunspot and Solr to do the full text searching then whatever javascript framework for the autocomplete.

Comment: Alternatively, `thinking_sphinx` and `sphinx`.